IDA show decimal values instead of hex and vertical alignment for ELF file
New to de-compiling, want to set up Ida to give best reading experience with ELF files from android phone.
I run in following issues:

Even though i set Edit > PlugIns > Hex-Rays Decompiler > Options > Default Radix = 10, still getting mixed HEX and decimal values for below function.
indent after = is not there in local IDA i want to align values vertically.

Output from https://dogbolt.org/ using Hex-Rays.
__int64 __fastcall GetSensorLibraryAPIs(__int64 result, double a2)
{
  *(double *)(result + 4) = a2;
  *(_QWORD *)(result + 16) = CalculateExposure;
  *(_QWORD *)(result + 24) = FillExposureSettings;
  *(_QWORD *)(result + 32) = FillPDAFSettings;
  *(_QWORD *)(result + 40) = FillAutoWhiteBalanceSettings;
  *(_QWORD *)(result + 72) = StatsParse;
  *(_QWORD *)(result + 80) = SetMinMaxAnalogRegisterGain;
  *(_QWORD *)(result + 48) = FillToneControlSettings;
  return result;

parsed with Ida on my PC
__int64 __fastcall GetSensorLibraryAPIs(__int64 inputVar, double a2)
{
  *(double *)(inputVar + 4) = a2;
  *(_QWORD *)(inputVar + 0x10) = CalculateExposure;
  *(_QWORD *)(inputVar + 24) = FillExposureSettings;
  *(_QWORD *)(inputVar + 0x20) = FillPDAFSettings;
  *(_QWORD *)(inputVar + 40) = FillAutoWhiteBalanceSettings;
  *(_QWORD *)(inputVar + 0x48) = StatsParse;
  *(_QWORD *)(inputVar + 80) = SetMinMaxAnalogRegisterGain;
  *(_QWORD *)(inputVar + 48) = FillToneControlSettings;
  return inputVar;
}

Source code from similar file
VOID GetSensorLibraryAPIs(
    SensorLibraryAPI* pSensorLibraryAPI)
{
    pSensorLibraryAPI->majorVersion                  = 1;
    pSensorLibraryAPI->minorVersion                  = 0;
    pSensorLibraryAPI->pCalculateExposure            = CalculateExposure;
    pSensorLibraryAPI->pFillExposureSettings         = FillExposureSettings;
    pSensorLibraryAPI->pStatsParse                   = StatsParse;
    pSensorLibraryAPI->pFillAutoWhiteBalanceSettings = FillAutoWhiteBalanceSettings;
    pSensorLibraryAPI->pUpdateMaxAnalogGain          = UpdateMaxAnalogGain;
}


is there way to set up ida to have more readable output similar to original source code?

Please suggest overall best suitable Ida settings for this file.


I upload source code and file here: https://www.upload.ee/files/16662735/ELF_and_Source_Code.zip.html

IDA doesn't know the type of the argument being passed to the function.
You can press Shift+F1 to go to Local Types. There you can insert a new type as struct and then Press Y to retype the function signature. A combination of Y and N can then be used to change types and names until you get as close to source as possible.
See Type Recovery for more details
